# Downloading a Google New Sites site file from Drive

Tags: google-drive

How may I download a Google New Sites site file from Drive? All Google New Sites site files in Drive have the regular Download command missing from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to use a [third party service](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-an-entire-Google-Site-hosted-on-Google-Sites-and-use-it-for-offline-viewing-or-hosting-it-on-a-local-server) to download all of the files of a Google Site

Comment: I don't want to download all the files sent to the browser. I want to download the single source file.

Comment: the standard way is to use Google Takeout (takeout.google.com).
Check this link: https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/how-to/export-with-takeout